# how to save edited image locally using aviary web widget and php

Tags: php, jquery

I plugged the feather aviary web widget into my site and it looks and plays fantastically.but I am having a hard time with php to save the edited images locally(from aviary server to my server) and i want to overwrite original image into edited image.i read the aviary documentation(www.aviary.com/web-documentation) but i don't understand how to save the edited images locally.
    here is aviary example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
        apiKey: '1234567',
        apiVersion: 2,
        tools: ['draw', 'stickers'],
        onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
            var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
            img.src = newURL;
        },
        postUrl: 'http://example.com/featherposturl'
    });

    function launchEditor(id, src) {
        featherEditor.launch({
            image: id,
            url: src
        });
        return false;
    }

</script>                         

<!-- Add an edit button, passing the HTML id of the image
    and the public URL to the image -->
<a href="#" onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1', 
    'http://example.com/public/images/goat.jpg');">Edit!</a>

<!-- original line of HTML here: -->
<img id="editableimage1" src="http://example.com/public/images/goat.jpg"/>
```

HERE is php coding:

```
<?php

    $image_data = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);

    file_put_contents("photo.jpg",$image_data);

?>
```